# Equivalente de onCreate()

Tags: android

Estou a reconstruir um conjunto de objetos para que os possa reutilizar em outras aplicações. Estes objetos não são atividades e apenas têm um conjunto de funções práticas que eu quero chamar a qualquer altura da execução de uma atividade.

Como posso ter um método `onCreate`nestes objectos sem ter de fazer `extends Activity`?
Este código dá erro:

```
public class Session {
    Context mContext;

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefs_editor;

    public Session(Context context){
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        prefs_editor = prefs.edit();
    }

    public Boolean is_user_logged(){
        return prefs.getString("login", "").equals("true");
    }

}
```

Mas se eu colocar `extends Activity` e passa a executar corretamente.
Existe algum tipo de `onCreate` onde eu posso fazer as minhas inicializações para o meu objeto sem ter de depender da class `Activity`?

**UPDATE**
O erro que dá é o seguinte:

```
Error:(19, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(21, 14) error: cannot find symbol method onCreate(Bundle)
```

Comment: Bom, normalmente é feito no próprio construtor da classe, como você já tem no seu código para atribuir o contexto.

Comment: O erro é por causa da notação `override`, que não deve existir neste caso porque você não estende nenhuma classe.

Comment: Se eu retirar o `override` sempre que eu chamar a class `Session session = new Session();` ele executa o método `onCreate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi da sua classe, você pode ter algo mais ou menos assim simplificado:

```
public class Session {
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefs_editor;

    public Session(Context context) {
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        prefs_editor = prefs.edit();
    }

    public Boolean is_user_logged() {
        return prefs.getString("login", "").equals("true");
    }
}
```

Inicialização:

```
Session session = new Session(context);
```

Verificação de usuário:

```
if (session.is_user_logged()) {
    // usuario autenticado
}
```

Editar:

```
session.prefs_editor.putString("login", foo);
session.prefs_editor.apply();
```

O construtor tem justamente esse objetivo, isso utilizando ainda a forma que você pretende com sua classe, mas você pode ainda utilizar essa classe como [*singleton*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton) que acredito ficar melhor.

Answer (score 1):

O que você pode fazer é simplesmente chama o seu `onCreate` na inicialização da sua `class` (que pelos comentários parecer já lhe atende),   já que no construtor você já terá a instância do contexto da aplicação, que é necessário em seu `onCreate()`, você pode fazer algo similar a isso:

```
public class Session {
    Context mContext;

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefs_editor;

    public Session(Context context){
        this.mContext = context;
        // chamar o seu onCreate ao inicializar a class
        onCreate();
    }

    // - Remova o override (já que sua classe não extents de nenhuma outra)
    // - Remova o parâmetro "Bundle savedInstanceState" do onCreate (já que o mesmo não é necessario)

    protected void onCreate() {
        // -- remova a chamada ao onCreate da class base (super), já que sua classe não extents de nenhuma outra

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        prefs_editor = prefs.edit();
    }

    public Boolean is_user_logged(){
        return prefs.getString("login", "").equals("true");
    }

}
```

Ou você simplesmente pode mover o conteúdo do método `onCreate` para o construtor e remover o método `onCreate`.